# How does react know where to put the cursor while typing inside an input element?

Tags: reactjs

If I write this in a component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
....
return <input onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
```

Then react somehow knows how to preserve the cursor position. I'm wondering - how does react do this exactly? All react knows is that I'm resetting the value of the input. Is there some sort of algorithm to find the added letter and add the cursor in at the right place?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with react.

Comment: You're right - I just tested in vanilla JS and I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special needs to be done.

The target value has been reassigned by the user by the time the React change callback runs; that's why the `setValue(e.target.value)` sets the *new* value in state, rather than the old value.

When the value is assigned to an input, if the new value is the same as the old value, the browser will not change the cursor position. Demo:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log('change seen');
  input.value = input.value;
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: Should probably mention how the mount identity of the component also matters - if you'd add `key={value}` to force remounts, focus and caret position will likely be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think you misunderstood my question...I have posted an answer myself.

Comment: @NickManning I think I understood it. With the input value already at the state the user's changed it to, React's assignment to the `.value` of the input doesn't result in the browser changing the input at all - the selection stays at the same point.

Comment: Oh okay now I see what you're saying! Makes sense...thanks!